# What a bitcoin node can do with its mempool "up-to-date" that another node can't without it's mempool updated?

Tags: mempool

I've figured out some answers but maybe there are other use cases:

1. Estimate fees by yourself.
2. Run a Stratum v2 miner choosing the txs you want to mine.
3. Have a service like http://mempool.space or http://mempoolexplorer.com
4. Relaying blocks faster since you already have the txs.